# unit test logic involving multiple classes

Tags: unit-testing

I have a subscription class with an assess method.
This methods gets the plan for this subscription (as an model) then this gets the fees for it.
With this the subscription contructs an invoice object that contains the fees that were not billed from the last billing date.

I would like to test this method but it seems to me that this would not be an unit test since it would involve many object with different dependencies.

How would you test this method ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean an `assess` method? An `asses` method sounds kinda wrong ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not a unit test for purists (rather an *integration test*), but still it may be a perfectly fine test :-) And technically you can run it with JUnit (or whichever your favourite unit testing framework is), so IMHO the difference is only in terminology.

If you write your code from scratch, it is best indeed to start by writing unit tests for individual methods in isolation (mocking out dependencies), then at the next stage maybe add higher level integration tests such as the one you describe, to verify that your classes work together well.

However, in legacy projects (i.e. lots of inherited code without tests), it is often not feasible to start with fine grained low-level unit tests; instead it is more efficient to write higher-level, more complex tests which clarify and "lock" the behaviour of a larger component.

Unfortunately the majority of projects in this industry by far is legacy :-( For me, in these cases, [pragmatism](http://pragprog.com/titles/tpp/the-pragmatic-programmer) wins over purity of approach hands down :-)

Comment: +1 you shouldn't care too much how it's called. If the damn thing is error prone, test the bejesus out of it.

Comment: I often use CppUnit and JUnit to test assemblies of classes, which are pedantically *integration tests* rather than *unit tests*. In fact, you can never really avoid doing this. Consider how many "low level classes" actually use STL or `java.lang` classes.

Answer (score 3):

As it stands this sounds like an integration test, not a unit test.

If you want to unit test the methods involved you should mock the dependencies (so you use a Mock Invoice to return known data). Then you can write unit tests separately to ensure the invoice class works.

Comment: IMHO, use of mock objects is not as necessary as many believe. Testing bottom up and accepting that it is OK to test assemblies of classes greatly reduces the need to mock objects/ test spies.